# Why does the active stake plus the rent reserve not equal to the total balance? How to correctly calculate the total balance?

Tags: account, staking, balance, rewards

So I am trying to report the difference balances on an staking account. My assumption was:

total balance = active stake + rent reserve

However, this equation is not true when looking at the numbers in the screenshot (https://solana.fm/address/DSXgo61hpLQsMnYioYMd4hycBgyZpvqSLKo5yo6zFRs9?cluster=mainnet-alpha)

total balance = active stake + rent reserve + **unknownBalance**

0.105477195 = 0.103175497 + 0.00228288 + **unknownBalance**

My assumption now is, is that the difference might be an additional balance for pending staking rewards which are already accounted for in the total balance. If so how can I query the RPC node (https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getinflationreward) to get the difference?

And is my assumption correct, that we do not receive rewards on the **unknownBalance**?

[image]

Comment: The difference on this address is substantial: https://solana.fm/address/FbGeZS8LiPCZiFpFwdUUeF2yxXtSsdfJoHTsVMvM8STh?cluster=mainnet-alpha

At the time of checking it is 1254.54079613 SOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can have more SOL on a staking account by sending more SOL to the account. That SOL is not staked and doesn't earn staking rewards, and can be withdrawn with a withdraw-stake instruction.